# Gather scores and show messages

Tags: javascript, html, triggers, save

I'm making a website, like cookie clicker, you have to click an object as many times as you can.

1. How can I show different messages, using either divs or alerts, when the user has reached for example 100 clicks? (When you've clicked the object 100 times, a message will appear.)
2. What's the easiest way to gather all users scores together and display as one?
   (Example: One player gets 100p and another one gets 200, they stop playing and a third player enters the website, how can I show "So far we've clicked 300 clicks!" at the page and then add the third player's score to the final number?)

Here's the current code which is working perfect:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    function countClicks() {
     count = count + 1;
        document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = count;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="space"></div>
<center><p id="counter">0</p></center>
<a href="javascript:countClicks();"><div id="face"></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a bit more infrastructure than you have.

The "old" way of handling this kind of situation is to use a server, and once in a while you update the server with the number of clicks you've sent.

You can't send each and every click because the user can click far faster than ajax requests can be run through the wire, so there will always be a delay and lag somewhere.

The other way to do it is through WebRTC.  There is a library which greatly simplifies that -- though it is never truly simple.

You can read about WebRTC and peerJS here: http://peerjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but are there not a simpler way? The total score doesn't need to be updated in real time, it would be great if I can use a "send to total" button when the user has finished clicking..

Comment: Sure, you can do that -- but uh -- you still need someplace to Send that data *to*.  Wither automated or manual, you still need to send that data *somewhere*.

Comment: a txt file? Or do I need a whole database?